# Vscode cannot download vscode server, what should I do?

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, remote, development

I tried to use SSH in Visual Studio Code to connect to my remote server but failed.
This the prompt:

- Could not establish connection toopengauss-deu':Failed to install the VS Code Server.
  How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you please provide detailed log for the failure? Have you looked at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72398492/could-not-establish-connection-to-hostname-the-vs-code-server-failed-to-start)

Comment: Thx for caring. Now I have resolve the problem. I just changed my Remote-SSH extension version to 0.100.0 and it worked. Before this I was using version 0.066.0.(I'd love to put a picture on but I don't know how to do.)